# Watir webdriver Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Updated:

I'm running the code below to execute my sample test cases: (Windows 7, Watir 3.0.0, Watir-webdriver-0.6.1)

```
require "watir-webdriver"
require 'test/unit'

class Teste1    
    $var = Watir::Browser.new :chrome       
    def met1
        $var.goto 'google.com'
        $var.text_field(:name, "q").set 'sample'
        $var.button(:name =>'btnG').click
    end     
end

class Teste2 < Test::Unit::TestCase 
    $test = Teste1.new
    def test_gomet1
        $test.met1()
    end     
end
```

The browser opens but the script throws the following error:

```
test_gomet1(Teste2):
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `response_for'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in `request'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `get'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:63:in `goto'
maisum.rb:11:in `met1'
maisum.rb:21:in `test_gomet1'
```

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: I would suggest that you try to reproduce the problem with as few lines of code as possible.

Comment: Removing `met2`, `test_gomet2` and `test_closeVar` I'm getting the same error, that's the fewest lines of code that I can reproduce the problem

Comment: Is the problem in test/unit code or in watir code? I would suggest that to try to reproduce the code without test/unit code.

Comment: I thik that the problem is in test/unit, cause when I remove `< Test::Unit::TestCase ` and call my method as `teste2 = Teste2.new; teste2.test_gomet1()` that works.

Comment: That is good information. So, calling the methods causes the problem.

Comment: Yes, and exists something that can fix it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14350/discussion-between-marcelo-and-zeljko-filipin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot get that exception for the `test_closeVar` test, however I can reproduce it for your other two tests. You get that exception when you try to interact with the browser after it has been closed.

When using Test::Unit, keep in mind that the tests run in alphabetically order. Therefore your `test_closeVar` test will close the browser before `test_gomet1` and `test_gomet2` even run. `test_gomet1` and `test_gomet2` will throw that exception because the browser is closed.

As a quick fix, you could add numbers to the test names to get them to run in a specific order.

The long term fix though is really to make your tests independent so that order does not matter.

**Update**

A couple of observations:

- The problem occurs using Selenium-Webdriver, so not a Watir-Webdriver specific issue.
- The script runs fine in Firefox, so it might be a chromedriver specific issue.

Workaround: It seems like the chrome browser does not like being declared outside the test case. I do not understand why, but the quick fix is to declare the browser in the setup of the test case. If you want to use the same browser for each test, you can just declare it if it does not already exist.

The following will run (though I would suggest cleaning it up to reduce the usage of global variables):

```
class Teste1    
    def met1
        $var.goto 'google.com'
        $var.text_field(:name, "q").set 'sample'
        $var.button(:name =>'btnG').click       
    end     
end

class Teste2 < Test::Unit::TestCase 
    def setup()
        unless defined?($var)
            $var = Watir::Browser.new :chrome       
        end
        $test = Teste1.new()
    end

    def test_gomet1
        $test.met1()
    end     
end
```

Comment: I've simply removed `test_CloseVar` test from my code and still got the same error.

Comment: Thanks Justin Ko, that worked, I'm a starter in Ruby/Watir and I'll try to improve my scripts