# Watir - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9518

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm a newbie in ruby and watir.  I'm trying to run the following lines:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'https://www.google.co.in/'
```

Chrome is opened, but the browser doesn't get google page.  I get the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9518
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:103:in `response_for'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:57:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:653:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:631:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:136:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in `to'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:77:in `goto'
    from (irb):17
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I looked for other topics and Q&A but I didn't found bright answer.

Comment: best explanation is already given in this stack link please check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584896/watir-webdriver-errnoeconnrefused-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-tar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584896/watir-webdriver-errnoeconnrefused-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-tar)

Comment: What are your chrome and chromedriver versions?  You should try to update to latest.

Comment: @orde I'm on the latest of both

Comment: @dsnraghavendrarao I read it several times and from what I understood is in that case - calling the methods causes the problem. I don't have any methods only simple script.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the recent version of Chrome driver, that's 2.25, This problem was resolved after I have put the recent version of Chrome driver.